# Преобразование числа long в массив int

Tags: java, массивы, java-8

Всем доброго времени суток!
Решаю задачку с условием: *Дается случайное положительное число, необходимо вернуть цифры этого числа в массив в обратном порядке.*

Для этого я написал следующий код:

```
 public static int[] digitize(long n) { ///!!!!!!
    // Code here
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(DigitsInNumbers(n));
    Collections.reverse(list);
    
    int [] myArr = new int [list.size()];
    for (int i = 0;i<myArr.length;i++){
        myArr[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    return myArr;
}
public static List<Integer> DigitsInNumbers (long number){
    String n = Integer.toString((int)number);
    char [] charArray = n.toCharArray();
    List<Integer> cia = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<charArray.length;i++){
        int c = Character.getNumericValue(charArray[i]);
        cia.add(c);
    }
    return cia;
}
```

При тестировании выдает такую ошибку: **Should work with some preset numbers: arrays first differed at element [0]; expected:<0> but was:<6>**

И иногда если число, например 2422044068. То вообще не дает запустить и говорит Intager number too large.

В целом, при интовых значениях работает.

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я накосячил :(

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Long это тот же Int, только разрядности больше. И (int) ни к чему

Comment: Это да, но по условию задачи метод именно такой. Поэтому и возникла проблема

Comment: Размер int от -2147483648 до 2147483647  поэтому и пишет что число 2422044068 слишком большое для интового диапозона

Comment: Да, я это понимаю. Но вот по условию метод возвращает интовый массив, а принимает лонговое число. И в общем то на это пофиг, так как я в своем коде разбиваю лонг на интовый массив цифр. Я не понимаю суть ошибки(

Comment: Почитай о приведении типов, тип int можно , так сказать впихнуть, в long, а вот наоборот нельзя, это будет уже переполнение

Comment: Понял, углублюсь в эту тему. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если ты выведешь данную строку

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

то увидишь, что у инта макс значение 2147483647
и такие числа как у тебя надо хранить в лонгах, добавляя `L` в конце числа.

ну и пару вариантов решения твоей задачи

```
//      перевести число в string
        String txt = String.valueOf(1235457678585L);
//      перевернуть строку
        String txt1 = String.valueOf(new StringBuilder(txt).reverse());
//1й вариант
         int[] arr1 = txt.chars()
                .map(x -> x - '0')
                .toArray();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));

// 2й вариант
         int[] arr2 = Stream.of(txt.split(""))
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .toArray();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));

//3й вариант
        int[] arr3 = new int[txt.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++) {
            arr3[i] = txt.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3));

//    в обратном порядке
        int[] arr4 = new int[txt.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++) {
            arr4[i] = txt.charAt(txt.length() - 1 - i) - '0';

        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr4));

//5й вариант
        char[] list = txt.toCharArray();
        int[] arr5 = new int[txt.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++) {
            arr5[i] = Character.digit(list[i], 10);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr5));
        
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!